# Week of the year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have one column in which I have to show the week of the another column `[Sales Stage Date]`.

I used

```
DATEPART( wk, [Sales Stage Date])
```

But the issue is it takes week from Sunday to Saturday but I want it to take it as Monday to Sunday.

Example: 1st Aug 2021 should be in week 31 and not in week 32.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with SET DATEFIRST function ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you looked at `iso_week` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: How do you define the year?  Is this a fiscal year - or standard calendar year?  If you are using a Fiscal year - is it a 4-4-5, 4-5-4 or 5-4-4 fiscal calendar or a typical fiscal calendar beginning on a set date every year (e.g. 10/1 through 9/30)?  Since this appears to be sales information - I suspect the week numbers need to be defined based on the retail 52/53 week calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub  a day off the date before you ask what week it's in
`DATEPART( wk, DATEADD(day, -1, [Sales Stage Date]))`

You'll need to handle the first day of the year directly with a CASE WHEN

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the language your `LOGIN` is using (American) `ENGLISH` and thus the first day of the week is Sunday.

One method would be to change your language, but this feels excessive and would be specific to your `LOGIN` only.

Another is to explicitly set the `DATEFIRST` setting to 1 prior to the statement:

```sql
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '20210802'),
       DATEPART(WEEK, '20210101');
```

This, however, would be explicit to the connection where you changed the value of `DATEFIRST` so if you use this logic a lot you'd need to continuously force the value of `DATEFIRST` (which could break other code).

Depending on your business neeeds, however, you might be better off investing in creating a calendar table. Then you can `JOIN` to that table, and get the values you need agnostic of the `LANGUAGE` and date settings.